# kotlin: extension methods and null receiver

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

In lombok extension method `obj.method()` is a syntax sugar for `SomeUtil.method(obj)`. It allows for `obj` be null.

Kotlin extensions methods are resolved statically so I assume it's the same syntactic sugar. But when I wrote

```
fun Any.stringOrNull() = this?.toString()
```

I got a warning about unnecessary safe call on non-null receiver. Does that mean I can't call extension functions on null objects like with Lombok?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call it on a nullable object if you define it to be an extension on a nullable type:

```
fun Any?.stringOrNull() = ...
```

Otherwise, like with any other method, you'd have to use the [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls).

Answer (score 14):

You can create extensions on nullable receiver types. In your example, it has to be `Any?` instead of `Any` which would not allow null, see the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#nullable-receiver):

> **Nullable Receiver**
>
> Note that extensions can be defined with a nullable receiver type. Such extensions can be called on an object variable even if its value is `null`, and can check for `this == null` inside the body. This is what allows you to call `toString()` in Kotlin without checking for `null`: the check happens inside the extension function.
>
> ```
> fun Any?.toString(): String {
>     if (this == null) return "null"
>     // after the null check, 'this' is autocast to a non-null type, so the toString() below
>     // resolves to the member function of the Any class
>     return toString()
> }
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Be careful, for:

```
fun Any?.toString(): String
```

following behavior:

```
var obj: Any? = null

obj?.toString() // is actually null
obj.toString() // returns "null" string
```

just spent 15 very frustrating minutes before realized this...

Answer (score 1):

> val string: String? = "Hello World!"
> print(string.length)
> // Compile error: Can't directly access property  of nullable type.
> print(string?.length)
> // Will print the string's length, or "null" if  the string is null.

### `?.` Safe Call operator for nullable receiver##

The safe call operator returns null if the value to the left is null, otherwise continues to evaluate the expression to the right, so in order to call any function on nullable receiver you need to use safe call operator after Any.(Use Any?)
Then you can check for null value of this(here `this object points to receiver`) inside function body.This is what allows you to call toString() in Kotlin without checking for null: the check happens inside the extension function.

> ```
> fun Any?.toString(): String {
>     if (this == null) return "null"
>     // after the null check, 'this' is autocast to a non-null type, so the toString() below
>     // resolves to the member function of the Any class
>     return toString()
> }
> ```